# SQL Where..Like clause for search criteria containing a Space and special characters like @, !, #

Tags: sql, ms-access-2010

Good day all,

I am trying a basic select query with Search Criteria as shown below on an Access Database table. Its not returning any values from the database table.

The search criteria which is the value from table contains a Space followed by `@`, and then other special characters like `!`, `#`.

Since I want to return all values matching this criteria, I am using `%` in the end. For testing purposes, if I specify the complete value as criteria then it works but would appreciate if someone can suggest a correct syntax for below query.

once sorted, I need to use in Vb .Net application. 
Thanks in advance.

```
SELECT linkage.Value, linkage.file
FROM linkage
WHERE (((linkage.Value) Like " @a=0027!!20003##%"));
```

Comment: Is `<space>@=` at the beginning of the `value`? If not, you need to put `%` at the beginning of the pattern.

Comment: If you are working within MS Access, the wild card is nearly always *, in VB.Net it is most likely to be %

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT linkage.Value, linkage.file
FROM linkage
WHERE (((linkage.Value) Like "% @a=0027!!20003##%"));
```

just put it between two `% %`